# using relayEvent

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have simple DelButton class:

```
DelButton = Ext.extend(Ext.Button, {
    ,disabled: false
    ,listeners: {
        ,selectionchange: function() {
            alert('!!!!');
        }
    ,initComponent:function() {
        this.relayEvents(this.grid.getSelectionModel(), ['selectionchange']);
        DelButton.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    }
});
```

```
buildTBar: function(config) {
    config.tbar = {}
    config.tbar.push(new DelButton({grid:this }))
}
```

,

```
buildConfig:function(config) {
    this.buildTBar(config)
}
```

,

```
AbstractEditorGridPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel, {
    initComponent:function() {
        var config = {
            defaults:{border:true, autoHeight:false }
        };
        this.buildConfig(config);
        Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));
        AbstractEditorGridPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

    }
```

Why relayEvent don't work in this case ? ( this.grid.getSelectionModel is exists )

Comment: Why would you fire a 'selectionchange' from a button?

Answer (score 0):

You have some minor issues. Try this:

```
AbstractEditorGridPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel, {
    initComponent:function() {
        var config = {
            defaults:{border:true, autoHeight:false }
        };
        this.buildConfig(config);
        Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    buildTBar: function(config) {
        config.tbar = [];
        config.tbar.push(new DelButton({grid:this, text: 'Text'}))
    },
    buildConfig:function(config) {
        this.buildTBar(config)
    }
});
```